# Reading contents from flash player in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a application,where if i click a link,it opens a flash player,inside that there is grid displayed with 20-30 rows..
Is it possible to read the contents using selenium webdriver.

**HTML Code :**

```
<embed id="mysSys" 
src="flex-ui/opr-event-browser.swf" 
flashvars="viewId=f746df4f-8f82-491e-b9dc-a82151953061" 
quality="high" 
bgcolor="#ffffff" 
name="EvtSys" 
allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" 
wmode="opaque" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
width="100%" align="middle" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's your flash app - it's easy. Your flash dev's need to inject extra library [Flex Pilot](https://github.com/mde/flex-pilot/wiki/api) for flash. Then you could navigate inside flash app, like in HTML DOM.

Some extras

- [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flex-pilot-x/?src=ss) for Selenium IDE
- or more powerfull [tool](http://www.monsterdebugger.com/)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Selenium can't read Flash content at all.
Flash elements cannot be accessed by Selenium either, unless you are targeting coordinates.

Comment: Selenium can :) You just need to convince flash to be more open ;)